# Slashed tyre? Or something else?

Tags: tires

Hi this is my first car so not an expert on these things yet, but my other half took my car to work and now this has happened to the tyre, it looks like someone has put a knife or something into the tyre, but maybe I'm wrong, what does everyone else think? [image][image]

Comment: Did they find anything inside the tire? Looks like either a screwdriver or bolt punctured it.

Doesn't look slashed. I found a spoon and a wrench inside someone's tire before while changing. :) So just know if you drive over something at the right (wrong?) angle or while turning, it can puncture the tire through the sidewall without being sharp. The sidewall plies are often nylon/textile/ or some other softer than metal material that will lose in a battle against metal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the white residue I would say some kind of impact. Also the sidewall has some deformation not typical of an intentional slash. The edges of the  hole itself looks too uneven to be from a knife or other tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that looks like a knife, but something that maybe triangular...

What ever it was you need to replace that tyre - sad as it looks as if it still had useful life left...

Comment: But for your safety get it replaced.

Comment: Yea definitely, it's totally flat on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Tires I have seen which are intentionally slashed have knife like slits or have a shape from a sharp spike.  This doesn't look like any of them, however when that happened, your tire went flat quickly. So it likely happened close to where you parked.  Any recall of anything you might have run over?  It doesn't look like you hit a curb or something like that, because there is no scuff mark.

Near the top of the picture there is debris similar in color to near the penetration.

Good luck figuring out the source.

Comment: Not sure as other half was driving, I thought maybe it looked like a screwdriver had been stabbed into it, hopefully get to the bottom of it soon!

Comment: Unless the person doing it was rather strong, a screwdriver normally has be be ground to a point.  But you do have the matching scuff debris...is there any more elsewhere on the tire?